# How to execute HTML code after user submit

Tags: html, input

I want the user to load Movie.swf size of their choice. I have two input boxes, one for width and one for the height. How can I execute the object with the size the user submitted?

I can't figure out how to make this work.

```html
//Let the user set the size for Movie.swf
<label for="fname">Width</label><br>
<input type="text" id="objW"><br><br>
  
<label for="fname">Height</label><br>
<input type="text" id="objH"><br><br>

//Movie.swf will load with a new size from the input box
<input type="submit" value="Execute"><br>

//Execute this line when submit
<object width="" height="" data="/Movie.swf"></object>
```

Comment: You do know that Chrome - and other major browsers - are completely dropping support for Flash later this year?

Comment: Yeah I'm fully aware, I just want to try something hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add javascript code for this part unless you are already using a framework. Also you should wrap the inputs inside a `form` tag and add an on submit `eventlistener`.

In current situation, following code should work:

```js
const objW = document.getElementById('objW');
const objH = document.getElementById('objH');
const submitInput = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
submitInput.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  /*if you want to display the object element after clicking input submit and replace all input fields*/
  body.innerHTML = `<object width="${objW.value}" height="${objH.value}" data="/Movie.swf"></object>`;

  /*or you can use following code if you always have object element in your html*/
  const object = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
  object.setAttribute("height", objH.value);
  object.setAttribute("width", objW.value);

});
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This script will need to be located **after** the `objW`, `objH`, and other elements in the page. Alternatively wrap it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event-listener.